# Is it possible to set DEFAULT TRANSACTION ISOLATION for all connections in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, snapshot-isolation

I want the default Transaction Isolation level to be SNAPSHOT.

How do I set this on a SQL Server 2016 database?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible to configure Snapshot Isolation (SI) as the default isolation level.

To use SI, the database must be enabled for Snapshot Isolation:

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
```

Then each connection must *explicitly request* SI, using for example:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
```

It *is* possible to set the default Read Committed isolation level to use row versioning (RCSI).

If Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI) is sufficient for your purposes, the setting is:

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

Further reading:

- [Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) (documentation)
- [How to set the default transaction isolation level server wide?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ialonso/how-to-set-the-default-transaction-isolation-level-server-wide) by Nacho Alonso Portillo