# What is isolation level of autocommit?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, isolation-level, auto-commit

I'm trying to make sense from "autocommit" concept.

Originally I've heart about it in the context of Java JDBC API [Connection.setAutoCommit(boolean autoCommit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit-boolean-)

Quick search revealed that the term is not specific to JDBC, PostgreSQL refer to "autocommit" too:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-start-transaction.html

> In the standard, it is not necessary to issue `START TRANSACTION` to start a transaction block: any SQL command implicitly begins a block. PostgreSQL's behavior can be seen as implicitly issuing a COMMIT after each command that does not follow `START TRANSACTION` (or `BEGIN`), and it is therefore often called **“autocommit”**. Other relational database systems might offer an **autocommit** feature as a convenience.

If it is widespread **what is isolation level of autocommit mode**?

Conceptually as we have only one SQL statement before implicit `COMMIT` *isolation levels almost make no sense for autocommit*. Only READ UNCOMMITTED might influence the result, other anomalies are defined in term of a sequence of SQL statements.

Can I alter autocommit isolation level to / away from READ UNCOMMITTED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default isolation level is controlled through [default_transaction_isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DEFAULT-TRANSACTION-ISOLATION) and is `read committed` in a standard installation.

You can check your current setting using:

```
show default_transaction_isolation;
```

As Postgres does not support (or implement) `read uncommitted` there is no need to change this "away from read uncommitted".

If you want to change the isolation level to "higher" one, even in autocommit mode, you can use:

```
set default_transaction_isolation = serializable;
```

The above will change the default for the current session (=connection).

Comment: Tnx. From your answer I infer that SQL standard doesn't define syntax for default isolation level. We have to use proprietary extensions via connection settings or `set` operator. This answer (for SQL Server) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221548/is-it-possible-to-set-default-transaction-isolation-for-all-connections-in-sql-s also supports idea that **syntax for default isolation level is vendor specific**.

Comment: `start transaction` and `set transaction` are part of the SQL standard as far as I know. As the SQL standard doesn't have a notion of "autocommit" to begin with (as the Postgres manual states) those are the "standard ways" to deal with isolation levels.

Comment: It looks like `set transaction` influences only previous `start transaction`. Yeah, it is SQL standard syntax but for explicit transactions. It doesn't influence "autocommit" mode (`show transaction_isolation;` wasn't changed if not in an explicit transaction). I believe provided `set default_transaction_isolation` is non-portable but can be used to change "autocommit" behavior. Tnx for helping!

Comment: @gavenkoa: as you seem to be using Java/JDBC: you can use `Connection.setTransactionIsolation()` to change the isolation level for the current connection - that would be database independent if you really need that

Comment: The SQL standard decrees that the default transaction isolation level be `SERIALIZABLE`, but no database that I have heard of implements that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I couldn't find any reference to your comment. It is *recommended* that database systems would be better off using `SERIALIZABLE` but not not mandated. _The execution of concurrent SQL-transactions at isolation level SERIALIZABLE is guaranteed to be serializable. A serializable execution is defined to be an execution of the operations of concurrently executing SQL-transactions that produces the same effect as some serial execution of those same SQL-transactions. A serial execution is one in which each SQL-transaction executes to completion before the next SQL-transaction begins._

Comment: @JohnK.N. SQL 2012, Chapter 4.36.4 "Isolation levels of SQL-transactions": *The isolation level of an SQL-transaction when any cursor is held open from the previous SQL-transaction within an SQL-session is the isolation level of the previous SQL-transaction by default. If no cursor is held open, or this is the first SQL-transaction within an SQL-session, then the isolation level is `SERIALIZABLE` by default.*

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you.